# arithmetic in r error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, math

Very simple quesiton, very hard in R for a newbie like me.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)

y <- c(1,2,3)
```

The object lengths are different. So i cant perform, let's say, z <- x + y

What is the best way to approach arithemetic of different object length. Add a 0?

Comment: You *can* perform z <- x + y. The shorter vector's elements would be recycled. You'll get a warning, not an error. See `?Arithmetic`. The question is why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To do this programmatically, you could first put the vectors in a named vector that we can run a grouping function on.

```
z <- setNames(c(x, y), c(seq_along(x), seq_along(y)))
#  1 2 3 4 1 2 3 
#  1 2 3 4 1 2 3
```

Now we can run a grouping function for the sum:

```
unname(tapply(z, names(z), sum))
# [1] 2 4 6 4
```